# How to inspect the console output via a USB cable?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a simple app installed on android and iOS devices after successfully running the command of `flutter run --debug/release`. This app prints a message to the output console every time a button is pressed. However, how can I inspect this console message on-demand every time I connect a USB cable, enable developer mode, and run the app from the app center?

Comment: You can try some of the options on `adb logcat` https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat  You'll want to look into the filtering options because otherwise you get a lot of noise from other apps.

Comment: You should avoid printing to console on release apps.

Comment: @Alaindeseine that is not always the case since I am debugging an issue that only occurs on release mode.

Comment: If the issue occurs in release mode, i suggest use `--release` with the `flutter run` command. For example, `flutter run -d <ID of device> --release`

You then run in release mode and have logs in console.